# Unable to follow "Sandbox" links from Mesos UI

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon

I have three physical nodes with docker installed on each of them. I configured Mesos,Marathon,Hadoop,Flink and Zookeeper on them. I can see all UI in my browser and run a Flink application in Marathon.

The problem is that Mesos UI shows me that Flink is running, but when I click on **SandBox**, I see this error:

> Failed to connect to agent '16657705-0573-410a-aef3-e2bb4119092c-S0' on '//50592e835da1:5051/slave(1)/state?jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK'.
>   Potential reasons:
>
> The agent is not accessible
>
> The agent timed out or went offline

I know it is related to Mesos configuration, but I have no idea what is wrong.

I wrote **MESOS_HOSTNAME** in **/etc/hosts**, but it did not work. Also, I sat **MESOS_HOSTNAME=IP** in **mesos-agent-env.sh**, but it did not work.

Would you please guide me how I can solve the issue?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. 
According to the Apache Mesos site, **The hostname the agent node should report, or that the master should advertise in ZooKeeper.**. I forgot to use **--hostname=SlaveIP** in slave command; after using it, every thing ran without any errors.

```
 /home/mesos-1.7.2/build/bin/mesos-slave.sh
  --master=10.32.0.2:5050,10.32.0.3:5050 --hostname=10.32.0.4
  --work_dir=/var/run/mesos --log_dir=/var/log/mesos 
  --systemd_enable_support=false
```